# Publishing the same app with different versions

Tags: android, google-play, publish, publishing

I'm working on an app and I want to have three versions for sale. Basically an economy, standard, and advanced version. I have a switch where you change a variable and that sets what version is compiled.

When I try to publish the app, it says that an app with the package name already exists.

Do I need to sign each package with a unique key, or do I need to change the whole package name for each version? If I need to change the package name, what is the easiest way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should convert your project to Android Library. And then create three application projects, each of which would have different package names with different "variable".

1. `com.you.package.economy`, -> sets variable to economy
2. `com.you.package.standard` -> sets variable to standard
3. `com.you.package.advanced`, -> sets variable to advanced

For more information about Android Libraries [see documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects). If you need more in-depth information how Android Libraries work [see my post](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/android-application-android-libraries-and-jar-libraries/).

Comment: Agreed. I would also check out my post on how to do this in detail over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221218/how-can-i-support-my-android-application-for-multiple-android-stores/6221880#6221880

Comment: This is correct and it is super sucky. It should be a manifest property instead of having to change the package names. One of the annoyances of android.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but I'm having a problem. I opted to leave the source package name the same com.bla.app and made the other versions use com.bla.app.version. When I try to run the app, I get a null pointer exception- it turns out that findViewById isn't working and is returning NULL... What am I forgetting?

Comment: Never mind the above, it was because eclipse auto generated another main.xml file. But now I'm having problems where my library wants to access files in the assets folder.